# How to uncheck a checkbox in pure JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, checkbox

Here is the HTML Code:

```
<div class="text">
   <input value="true" type="checkbox" checked="" name="copyNewAddrToBilling"><label>
```

I want to change the value to false. Or just uncheck the checkbox. I'd like to do this in pure JavaScript, without the use of external libraries (no jQuery etc)

Comment: Just `checkBoxElem.checked = false`!

Answer (score 70, accepted):

```
<html>
    <body>
        <input id="check1" type="checkbox" checked="" name="copyNewAddrToBilling">
    </body>
    <script language="javascript">
        document.getElementById("check1").checked = true;
        document.getElementById("check1").checked = false;
    </script>
</html>
```

I have added the language attribute to the script element, but it is unnecessary because all browsers use this as a default, but it leaves no doubt what this example is showing.

If you want to use javascript to access elements, it has a very limited set of GetElement* functions.  So you are going to need to get into the habit of giving every element a UNIQUE id attribute.

Comment: But as most of your response are demonstrating most javascript programmers who modify elements of the HTML DOM usually find there way to jQuery or some other similar framework, because it makes coding a lot easier

Comment: Is there a way to do this without adding the id tag in the html code? Is there a way to do it by name?

Comment: Not really, jQuery is the way to go for traversing the element DOM in anything more complex fashion than element types and element ids or the element class property

Comment: @Strings you're right, but it's not impossible to do it without giving the element an ID. See the `querySelectorAll` method described in my answer.

Comment: It's just as easy to do it by name `formName.checkboxName.value` or you can opt for the array of input elements `formName.elements[indexOfElement]`.

Comment: Also, the DOM isn't hard to traverse.  Yes, it's difficult to try maintaining something ridiculous like someElement.childNodes[2].getElementsByTagName('span')[1] but hey, it helps pave the way to understanding DOM manipulation.  I love jQuery, but it isn't needed for every simple task; selecting an element, in almost any reasonable case, isn't difficult.  JavaScript has many selectors available and don't forget you can store a reference to a node; this is especially easy if you've created the element dynamically.

Comment: *Correction: `formName.checkboxName.checked`

Comment: The problem is the scope of this and the other question overlap; I do agree there isn't a relevant answer there.  The other allowed a jQuery option and everyone seemed run with it.  This isn't a good example of the system "working right".  Maybe a relevant answer should be added to the other question (buried beneath the mound of jQuery answers), maybe this should be re-opened.  Feel free to flag the question to be reopened yourself.  Mods make mistakes and questions get reopened.

Comment: Is there a way to toggle?

Answer (score 13):

**Recommended, without jQuery**:

Give your `<input>` an ID and refer to that. Also, remove the `checked=""` part of the `<input>` tag if you want the checkbox to start out unticked. Then it's:

```
document.getElementById("my-checkbox").checked = true;
```

**Pure JavaScript, with no Element ID (#1)**:

```
var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('input');

for(var i = 0; i<inputs.length; i++){

  if(typeof inputs[i].getAttribute === 'function' && inputs[i].getAttribute('name') === 'copyNewAddrToBilling'){

    inputs[i].checked = true;

    break;

  }
}
```

**Pure Javascript, with no Element ID (#2)**:

```
document.querySelectorAll('.text input[name="copyNewAddrToBilling"]')[0].checked = true;

document.querySelector('.text input[name="copyNewAddrToBilling"]').checked = true;
```

Note that the [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) and [`querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) methods are supported in these browsers: IE8+, Chrome 4+, Safari 3.1+, Firefox 3.5+ and all mobile browsers.

If the element may be missing, you should test for its existence, e.g.:

```
var input = document.querySelector('.text input[name="copyNewAddrToBilling"]');
if (!input) { return; }
```

**With jQuery**:

```
$('.text input[name="copyNewAddrToBilling"]').prop('checked', true);
```

Comment: querySelectorAll() is a fairly new piece of core javascript, and is far from being available in the majority of active browser population at the moment.  This document by the author of jQuery is also worth reading before touting querySelectAll() as a jQuery alternative http://ejohn.org/blog/thoughts-on-queryselectorall/

Comment: @Strings Actually I still think this answer is just as valid. Especially as it champions alternatives. In his comments, the OP asked for an approach that didn't involve him adding an ID to the input. The `querySelectAll` is supported by IE8+, Firefox 3.5+, Chrome 4+, Safari 3.1+, and all mobile browsers. I don't think that's inadequate for every user-case. I'm not saying `querySelectorAll` is for everybody, but I think it's worth including - especially if we're striving to drive the web forward.

Comment: @Shennan I AGREE... querySelectorAll() is a very valid alternative (and also becoming more so as people upgrade their browser/computer), but sadly when using core javascript the target platform and userbase become almost as important as quality of your code.  I would also correct myself - the function does exists in the *majority* of browsers, it's just the minority (ie<7) and the incomplete implementation in ie8 that should cause concern.  Because demographically users using old versions of ie are the same users who frequently don't know how to help themselves out of browser problems.

Comment: @Strings I've edited the answer to be a bit clearer on my position.

Answer (score 5):

There is another way to do this:

```
//elem - get the checkbox element and then
elem.setAttribute('checked', 'checked'); //check
elem.removeAttribute('checked'); //uncheck
```

Answer (score 1):

You will need to assign an ID to the checkbox:

```
<input id="checkboxId" type="checkbox" checked="" name="copyNewAddrToBilling">
```

and then in JavaScript:

```
document.getElementById("checkboxId").checked = false;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
    <body>
        <input id="mycheck" type="checkbox">
    </body>

    <script>
        var check = document.getElementById("mycheck");
        check.checked = false;
    </script>
</html>
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your code. Code only answers are discouraged on SO.