# Why can I not change the 'checked' status of a checkbox in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, checkbox

**Intended behaviour**

I have a checkbox inside of a div element.  I want both the box and the div to be clickable.

- When the checkbox is clicked by the user, a class is added to the div to change its background colour.  This class is then removed if the checkbox is clicked again.
- When the div itself is clicked, the class with the background colour is added or removed as appropriate **and the checkbox is ticked or unticked too**

Currently, I have most of this working using plain javascript:

```js
function boxPress(markNumber) {
  var checkbox = "mark" + markNumber;
  var element = document.getElementById(checkbox);
  var markbox = "markbox" + markNumber;
  if (element.getAttribute("checked") == null) {
    element.setAttribute("checked", "checked");
    document.getElementById(markbox).classList.add('checked');
  } else {
    element.removeAttribute("checked");
    document.getElementById(markbox).classList.remove('checked');
  }
}
```

```css
.mark {
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  border-width: 2px;
  border-radius: 0px 5px 5px 0px;
  border-left-style: solid;
  border-left-width: 10px;
  border-color: lime;
  overflow: auto;
  padding: 2%;
  transition: background-color 0.5s linear 0s;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.checked {
  background-color: #66ff66;
}

.mark:hover {
  background-color: #fffcaf;
}

.checked:hover {
  background-color: #b3ffb3;
}

.flex-container {
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

.flex-mark {
  width: 85%;
  margin: 0px;
}

.flex-tick {
  width: 15%;
  margin: 0px;
  text-align: center;
}

.flex-tick input {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
}
```

```html
<div class="mark col-12 col-m-6" id="markbox0" onclick="boxPress(0)">
  <div class="flex-container">
    <div class="flex-mark">
      <p>Candidate introduces themself by first name, surname and role</p>
    </div>
    <div class="flex-tick"><input type="checkbox" id="mark0"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This works perfectly, apart from where the user first interacts with the checkbox, then later with the div element.

**Steps to reproduce the problem in the above snippet:**

1. Click the div.  The background changes and the checkbox is ticked.
2. Click the div again.  The changes are reversed as expected.
3. Click the checkbox.  The background change is applied.
4. Click the checkbox again.  The change is reversed as expected.
5. **Now click the div again.  The background changes happen but the checkbox remains unticked**

Even more interestingly, the HTML of the checkbox reads:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="mark0" checked="true">
```

Yet the browser doesn't render the box as checked.

Why is this happening, and why is it only a problem when the div click comes after the box click?  It happens in both Chrome and Edge.

Comment: I cannot reproduce the issue in Chrome, it works as expected after `15` cliks

Comment: Because the value of the `checked` attribute should not be `true`, it should be `checked` or not present. See [the standard](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/infrastructure.html#boolean-attributes).

Comment: did you try calling checkbox's click() ?

Comment: Or you could just set the `checked` **property** to true or false like `element.checked = true;`. See the dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/q/18862149/215552

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to uncheck a checkbox in pure JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18862149/how-to-uncheck-a-checkbox-in-pure-javascript)

Comment: @VMAtm I'm seeing it in Chrome 59 and Edge 38, with files on localhost (WAMP) but also in the above code snippet.  Is anyone else seeing the issue?

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan thanks, I've changed the code to match the standard but the error persists as it originally did.  Adding the 'checked=checked' element works for me the first time, just not in the specific situation described above.

Comment: Correct me if i'm wrong, but you want that if you click the div, the checkbox changes too, don't you? In your if/else condition you should add something like "if my div has this class or my checkbox is checked", not just checking your checkbox

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is a difference between the attribute checked and the checked state of a checkbox. Fixed code below.

**Explanation:**

Because the `checked` attribute can be set in the markup to "pre-check" the checkbox the DOM has to have a `checked` state for the checkbox or it would be impossible to "un-check" it. A checkbox that could not be un-checked wouldn't be very useful.

When you set the attribute for the first time (with javascript) it checks the box just like if you had put it in the HTML but the DOM ignores the attribute after that because it needs to rely on the checked state as explained above.

```js
function boxPress(markNumber) {
  var checkbox = "mark" + markNumber;
  var element = document.getElementById(checkbox);
  var markbox = "markbox" + markNumber;
  if (element.getAttribute("checked") == null) {
    element.setAttribute("checked", "true");
    element.checked = true;
    document.getElementById(markbox).classList.add('checked');
  } else {
    element.removeAttribute("checked");
    element.checked = false;
    document.getElementById(markbox).classList.remove('checked');
  }
}
```

```css
.mark {
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  border-width: 2px;
  border-radius: 0px 5px 5px 0px;
  border-left-style: solid;
  border-left-width: 10px;
  border-color: lime;
  overflow: auto;
  padding: 2%;
  transition: background-color 0.5s linear 0s;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.checked {
  background-color: #66ff66;
}

.mark:hover {
  background-color: #fffcaf;
}

.checked:hover {
  background-color: #b3ffb3;
}

.flex-container {
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

.flex-mark {
  width: 85%;
  margin: 0px;
}

.flex-tick {
  width: 15%;
  margin: 0px;
  text-align: center;
}

.flex-tick input {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
}
```

```html
<div class="mark col-12 col-m-6" id="markbox0" onclick="boxPress(0)">
  <div class="flex-container">
    <div class="flex-mark">
      <p>Candidate introduces themself by first name, surname and role</p>
    </div>
    <div class="flex-tick"><input type="checkbox" id="mark0"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That works perfectly, thank you!  Could you explain it a bit more for me?  Why did it work on the first click of the div but not if the checkbox had been interacted with?

Comment: @Rory I added the explanation for you as requested. If you wouldn't mind accepting my answer it would be appreciated.