# How to uncheck HTML box if user hits cancel on prompt in Angular change event

Tags: angular

**Goal:** User hits a checkbox that kicks off my function checkedAmPrompt. If the users hits cancel on the prompt it will then uncheck the box they checked. If they hit OK it will continue as planned and stay checked. Currently it functions fine except that I cannot find a way to uncheck the box.

Relevant code below:

**webpage.component.html** -- note this is in a table where there is a check box corresponding to each row.

```
<td><input type="checkbox" class="form-control" id="checkedAm" (change)="checkedAmPrompt($event)"></td>
```

**webpage.component.ts**

```
// Prompt to confirm checkbox action
checkedAmPrompt(event: any) {
  const confirm = prompt('If you are certain that what you are doing is correct please type CONFIRM to continue.');

  // What to do if user selects cancel to pop-up, otherwise user confirms action
  if (confirm == null) {
    console.log('User hit cancel.');
    // ***** WANT TO PUT LOGIC TO UNCHECK HERE *****
  } else if (confirm.toLowerCase() === 'confirm') {
    // submit the changes if they type in confrim
    console.log('changes submitted!')
  } else {
    // if they misspell confirm let them know
    console.log('Incorrect spelling.');
  }
}
```

Logic for unchecking the HTML box will replace `// ***** WANT TO PUT LOGIC TO UNCHECK HERE *****`

Please note that I am not using JavaScript, my HTML file only contains HTML/Angular and all functions are referenced by the component typescript. I am very new to everything so please excuse me if this is a poor choice.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to uncheck a checkbox in pure JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18862149/how-to-uncheck-a-checkbox-in-pure-javascript)

Comment: In general, Angular HTML should reflect the current state of the app. My guess is you need to use something like `$scope.checkedAm = false;` and change the HTML accordingly: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChecked

Answer (score 2):

Just use `document.getElementById('checkedAm').checked = false`, does that work?

Comment: I get the following error: " Property 'checked' does not exist on type 'HTMLElement'."

Also note that I tried using a checked="true" or "false" but both true and false result in the box being checked.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ng-checked="(var bool or function that return bool)"`

Comment: I have tried this. Even with directly setting ng-checked="true" inside the input it still shows the box as unchecked.

Comment: try to use ng-change instead of (change) and tell me if it's okey

Comment: This does not work either and this causes my function not to execute. Thanks for trying though.

Answer (score 0):

Figured out what I needed to do.

HTML:

```
[checked]="checkCheck()"
```

Component:

```
checkCheck () {
return true;
}
```