# toggle checkbox with javascript

Tags: javascript, checkbox

I want to uncheck a checkbox using javascript. I have one button which just unchecks the box and works fine:

```
function clear() {
document.getElementById("check").checked = "";
}
```

I have another button that I want to check the box if not checked and uncheck if it is. Below doesn't uncheck the box. I can can switch the if statement and does works the opposite way. What's the problem?

```
function switchIt() {
if (document.getElementById("check").checked !== "checked") {
  document.getElementById("check").checked = "checked";
} else {
  document.getElementById("check").checked = "";
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Can you post your code for the checkbox inputs please.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to uncheck a checkbox in pure JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18862149/how-to-uncheck-a-checkbox-in-pure-javascript)

Answer (score 4):

`switch` is a [reserved word](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch), use another one

```js
function switchIt() {
  var box = document.getElementById("check");
  
  if (box.checked) {
    box.checked = false;
  } else {
    box.checked = true;
  }
}

setInterval(switchIt, 1000);
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="check" />
```

Comment: switch wasn't the actual name. Tried this and works perfectly so thanks @taki

Answer (score 2):

Treat "checked" as a boolean, not as a string.

You can just invert it, as in

```
element = document.getElementById("check")
element.checked = !element.checked
```

A more featured example:

```js
var $toggle = document.getElementById('toggle');
var $checkbox = document.getElementById('checkbox');



var toggle_checkbox = function() {
   $checkbox.checked = !checkbox.checked;
}

$toggle.addEventListener('click',toggle_checkbox);
```

```html
<label>
  Checkbox:
  <input id="checkbox" type="checkbox" checked />
</label>
<button id="toggle">Toggle</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need a boolean to do that.

Take a look at this pen:

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/jJyXgO

```
let checkbox = document.querySelectorAll('#check')[0]

setInterval(function() {
  checkbox.checked = !checkbox.checked
}, 1000)
```

Answer (score 0):

I've never seen it done with a string "checked" before. Try with a boolean like:

```
function change() {
    if (document.getElementById("check").checked !== true) {
      document.getElementById("check").checked = true;
    } else {
      document.getElementById("check").checked = false;
    }
}
```

or easier

```
function change() {
    document.getElementById("check").checked = !document.getElementById("check").checked
}
```

Don't forget, **switch** is reserved, so use a different name, as I did with change()